# LoadControl in a static scriptmethod does not adhere page lifecycle (Init event is not raised)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, page-lifecycle

I'm using a `ScriptMethod` which is called from Javascript. Inside this method I try to use `LoadControl` to programmatically get a control.

I'm adding this control to the current `IHttpHandler` (`HttpContext.Current.Handler`) which is an instance of the `Page` that also contains my (static) `ScriptMethod`. To this instance I add the control which is loaded using `LoadControl` however the `Init` event of my control is never raised.

**Is it possible to use `LoadControl` in a `ScriptMethod` while adhering the page lifecycle?**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [execute the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150027.aspx) which contains the control to get the relevant events to fire:

```
static void RenderControlTo(string pathToControl, TextWriter writer)
{
   var page = new Page();
   var control = page.LoadControl(pathToControl);
   page.Controls.Add(control);

   HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
}
```